# Android Studio Modificar parte grafica del xml, desde codigo java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml

espero explicar bien lo que quiero lograr:

Estoy desde codigo java, definiendo buttons,TextView etc.
pero estoy teniendo problemas al definirle sus propiedades, especificamente a por ejemplo:
a un boton, darle propiedad de padding,margin etc. Me gustaria como acceder a esa parte desde el codigo java.

Comment: hola, ¿puedes compartir lo que llevas, para no escribirte todo el código?

Comment: Fernando, recuerda que es importante agregues detalles específicos en este caso tu código, layout o imagen sobre el problema, para que no sea definida como una pregunta para cierre...

Answer (score 3):

#### Definir padding en una vista, programaticamente.

Para definir el padding de un botón programaticamente, se realiza mediante el método [setPadding()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPadding(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)), si revisas la documentación, se indica que los valores  enteros que se definen como argumentos son:

[setPadding(padding izquierdo, padding superior, padding derecho, padding inferior)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPadding(int,%20int,%20int,%20int))

Este es un ejemplo:

```
    Button mybutton = new Button(getApplicationContext());   
    //mybutton.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);                     
    mybutton.setPadding(10,20,10,20);
```

---

#### Definir margen en una vista, programaticamente.

Para definir un margen  progamaticamente, se realiza definiendo un [`LayoutParams`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html), en el cual puedes definir valores del margen similar a `setPadding()`, ejemplo:

```
    Button mybutton = new Button(getApplicationContext());   
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    //params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
    params.setMargins(10, 20, 10, 20);
    mybutton.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Documentación:

[Tamaño, padding y márgenes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html?hl=es)